# Mail form (PHP, AJAX)

Tags: php, ajax, forms, email, contacts

I am trying to make a simple website for a hotel, but I cannot recieve any e-mail from the website to my inbox. I bought a bootstrap theme, i inserted the e-mail to which i want to recieve the e-mail and i can send it as well but when i look in the inbox, i do not see any e-mail. The file "mail.php" has the following code:

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{    
    ##################################################################################################################
    
    // Email Settings
    $site_title     = "Hotel Centro Cavour";
    $to_email       = "info@hotelcentrocavour.it"; 
    $subject        = "Hotel Centro Cavour - New Message"; 
    
    // Output Messages
    $success_mssg   = "Your message has been sent successfully. Thank you.";               
    $error_mssg     = "An error has occurred. Please check your PHP email configuration."; 
    $short_mssg     = "Too short message! Please enter something.";                      
    $empty_fields   = "Input fields are empty! Please enter something.";              
    $name_mssg      = "Name is too short or empty! Please enter something.";             
    $email_mssg     = "Please enter a valid email!";                                  
    
    //Email Text
    $tr_name    = "Name";
    $tr_email   = "Email";
    $tr_message = "Message";
    $tr_phone   = "Phone Number";
    
    ##################################################################################################################

    //Check if its an ajax request, exit if not
    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {
    
        //Exit script outputting json data 
        $output = json_encode(
        array(
            'type'=>'error', 
            'text' => 'Request must come from Ajax'
        ));
        
        die($output);
    } 
    
    //Check $_POST vars are set, exit if any missing
    if( !isset($_POST["user_name"]) || !isset($_POST["user_email"]) || !isset($_POST["user_message"]) )
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => $empty_fields));
        die($output);
    }

    //Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var(). *PHP 5.2.0+
    $user_name        = filter_var($_POST["user_name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_email       = filter_var($_POST["user_email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $user_message     = filter_var($_POST["user_message"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_phone       = filter_var($_POST["user_phone"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_subject     = filter_var($_POST["user_subject"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    if(!empty($user_subject)){
        $subject = $user_subject;
    }
    
    //Additional php validation
    if(strlen($user_name)<4) // If length is less than  it will throw an HTTP error.
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => $name_mssg));
        die($output);
    }
    //Check Email
    if(!filter_var($user_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) //email validation
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => $email_mssg));
        die($output);
    }

    //Check Message
    if(strlen($user_message)<10) 
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => $short_mssg));
        die($output);
    }

    //Headers
    $headers = 'From: '.$site_title.' <'.$user_email.'>' . PHP_EOL .
    'Reply-To: '.$user_name.' <'.$user_email.'>' . PHP_EOL .
    'MIME-Version: 1.0' . PHP_EOL .
    'Content-type:text/html;charset=utf-8' . PHP_EOL .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    
    $message = "Name: $user_name <br> -- Email: $user_email <br> -- Phone: $user_phone <br> -- Message: $user_message";
    
    $sendemail = @mail($to_email, $subject, $message, $headers);
    
    if(!$sendemail)
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => $error_mssg));
        die($output);
    }else{
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => $success_mssg));
        die($output);
    }
}else{

    header('Location: ../404.html');

}
?>
```

Comment: is this on a localhost or live. Is your smtp set up?

Comment: How far through does it get? Does your code think it's sending the email but it never arrives, or does it stop before then? I'd advise against trying to send emails "from" the address the form-filler supplied, most commercial email servers will be configured to only send from a domain they're configured for, to prevent open relay. You could also look at using PHPMailer instead of the built-in mail function as I read that it's "better". If you remove the error-suppressing `@` symbol does that tell you anything?

Comment: This thread may give you tips to troubleshoot your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644436/php-mail-function-doesnt-complete-sending-of-e-mail

Comment: You say it doesn't arrive in your in-box, presumably you've checked for junk mail and so on?